# windows 10 BCD issue [UPDATE 11/3/23]

Tags: windows-10, boot, bootloader, bcd

Relevant specs: GPT format, ASUS  Q503U (laptop 2016), UEFI, main drive is NTFS, boot drive partition is FAT32

First, the status of my hard drive seems okay-ish when I've checked the status of it through crystal disk and other means. I do plan to swap my HDD for an SSD when I can get this sucker running again and run a checkdisk, sfc and dism scan when I have access to even open safe mode.

So leading to my current situation, all of a sudden one day my computer just went into recovery environment and didn't ever stop. The error I kept getting was something among the lines of "windows could not start properly" with no error code. I've been trying all sort of commands and nothing worked and then I saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZ17JrgFFhw) that seemed promising, to format the boot partition and insert the EFI from the windows folder which seemed to go smoothly.

But then I restarted my computer after that, and now my error code is 0x00001 and then I select "put into recovery environment" and yeild 0x000098. I've tried the basic few commands `/fixmbr`,  `/fixboot`, and `/rebuildbcd`. But I noticed when I did that final one, it said "windows installations: 0". Which does not sound too good.

So I checked my windows folder in my main drive `C:`, and saw that there was no BCD file at all! So I went to check the newly formatted partition and the EFI folder was completely empty! I'm not sure what happened, I believe when I followed the video all the files were all there.

**I have a Windows ISO USB, that I followed some tutorials to make. And I want to know how I can insert those files EFI, or BCD how however it may be, from the ISO USB to the boot partition and not use the ones that are in my `C:` drive which seem to be missing some files.**

I'm not exactly pro-reseting my windows because I have some brushes in my drawing program that I can not find out how to access them without going inside the program itself. I've used HIREN CD PE but I don't know how exactly to use it beyond just checking my files.

Let me know if you need anymore information or specs.

p.s. I'm not sure if I did something to change this, but the backup file I made while following the video doesn't seem to be there anymore...

**UPDATE WITH MORE INFORMATION (11/2/23)**

Here is some more information that I have recalled since making this post.
prior to this formatting thing:

- my restore point wouldn't load it would just loop me back to the initial advanced repair options screen (have not checked since
  formatting)
- when I ran scans chkdsk yielded: unspecified error occurred (75736e6a726e6c2e 500)
- sfc /scannow yielded: windows resource protection could not perform the requested operation-DISM didn't want to do anything because it's
  in "windows PE"
- I followed a more intensive DISM video tutorial by the same guy that made the video in the name

As of right now some notable things I can recall:

- I turned off fastboot a few days ago before formatting. I ran an automatic repair again hoping it would fix it but lead me down the
  same loop. I have not re-enabled it since then.
- when I formatted the volume I didnt assign its original label/name after and it removed the letter I assigned it.
  when I assigned a letter to a volume the other day I found that the EFI folder is empty, it no longer has that letter assigned anymore
- when I was in the process of loading the restore point it noted that an update for firefox was causing an issue. I don't browse fishy
  websites and I remember I was having some problems with firefox in
  general a few days prior to this debacle. (It basically wouldn't open
  or kept crashing something like that) but then I recall it did get
  fixed but still wanted to note that.
- on of my last attempts I followed this video  which has a command of `bootsect /nt60 sys` which i was a bit fishy about since my partition
  is a FAT32 type and from my understanding this is changed the format
  to NTSF or something. I still went through and did this and it didn't
  do anything from what I can tell. (I know it's labeled as windows 11)
  [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOihh4ZNOf4)
- this video(labeled as windows 10) also similar structure in code
  where it  talks about using `bootsect /nt60 sys` and
  their partition is NTSF instead of FAT32. Looking more into this
  videos advice through their website they mention formatting the
  partition to NTSF beforehand, which I don't know their repercussions
  of doing that so I have not touched trying this advice.
  [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fK38T6WVpGY)

**memory test**

I made a text file right now on the HDD and USB  im loading the RE from labeled "testUSB/HDD" and with some text matching the location and shut off. I booted again and the files were still in it's place. I'm not sure why my backup files I may have made following any video tutorial can not be found in the OS directory(? I mean where it says user, windows, in like the first directory when you're in the fire explorer looking at a main dive)

**update 11/3/23**

[photo of `diskpart /listvol` also `Bcdedit /enum | find "osdevice"`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUqLX.jpg)

(please tell me if I'm using incorrect phrases here)

vol 0: main drive

vol 1: folder labeled "EFI"

vol 2: folder labeled "recovery"

vol 3: usb with windows ISO running RE

- vol 1 is the drive that was formatted. It was originally labeled as SYSTEM but I didn't add the rename to it
- vol 2 when i checked inside of it, it was empty even before the whole formatting but i could still run the recovery environment

Comment: Which video? Can you spend more time turning this mess into a readable question?

Comment: @Gantendo sorry I put the video in a link but it doesn't seem to be showing. The video is this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZ17JrgFFhw as for the unreadable mess I'm trying my best I'm not too knowledgeable and just wrote what I found from my research, sorry. Let me know what you need cleared up please.

Comment: After 20 years of running Windows, and having similar issues with storage devices, I have never been able to recover from the type of system corruption your system likely has suffered from once Windows isn’t able to load.

Comment: @Ramhound Oh man I don't like the sound of that :( Do you have any ideas on how this may have been caused?

Comment: @meowington - In 100% of the cases I have dealt with, Windows boot issues their severe were always caused, by a failure in the storage device. 8 year old HDD is likely the issue.

Comment: @Ramhound how come when I used crystal disk through HIREN it says it's at a yellow state and when I do check disk or the cmd prompt tells me that its a healthy state?

Comment: Check disk is aware of the health of the disk, which is limited by the firmware of the device, the fact you have system corruption suggests something isn’t right about the disk. You should expect issues with a disk that was constantly used for 8 years.

Comment: @Ramhound So are your suggest that it's possibly a physical thing? Why is it only that system partition is dealing with this? I checked my files with HIREN and they all seemed to be fine even the last drawing file I made. (yes, I backed up my files)

Comment: @meowington - That’s how disk failures work. You might have multiple partitions but it’s still all the same disk platters or flash memory that in the case of an SSD

Comment: @Ramhound so could i clone my HDD to and SSD and then reset windows on the SSD? or how would i go around to porting my data to the SSD?

Comment: Modern versions of Windows cannot be installed on FAT32 only NTFS. Windows hasn’t been installed on FAT32 for more than 2 decades

Comment: @Ramhound Oh i think I see were the confusion on my update may rise, I'll go fix that. when I said my FAT32 partition I was referring to my boot volume that was labeled SYSTEM and had the EFI folder, my main drive is NTFS formatted

Comment: EFI is never NTFS

Comment: @Ramhound Oh I thought the order for booting was UFEI>EFI>BCD? what does NTFS formatting use then?